# DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping via ContextLoaderListener instead of DispatcherServlet on Spring 3

Tags: java, spring

When I use *DispatcherServlet*, I get a *java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?*
 error when I use a *DelegatingFilterProxy* filter. Therefore I've removed the *DispatcherServlet* and now I use a *ContextLoaderListener* instead, and my Spring application loads fine. However, I have a problem with one VERY important bean:

```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain"/>  
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
      <property name="interceptors">
         <list>
            <ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptor" />
         </list>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

This bean no longer works, none of my @Controller's are URL mapped anymore. If I switch back to using *DispatcherServlet*, no problem (except that my filter is useless again). How can I get this bean to load correctly from within a *ContextLoaderListener*?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need both the `ContextLoaderListener` *and* the `DispatcherServlet` - the error message didn't tell you to remove the servlet.

To clarify what Spring is doing here, the `DispatcherServlet` creates its own `ApplicationContext` (typically using `xxx-servlet.xml`), but any Spring Filters that you configure in web.xml don't have access to the servlet's `ApplicationContext`.

The `ContextLoaderListener` creates a second `ApplicationContext` (associated with the whole webapp), and links itself with the servlet's `ApplicationContext`, allowing filters and servlets to communicate via Spring.

Comment: Aha! That's VERY clarifying. :-) But, do you have any good links on how I can configure the ContextLoaderListener to dip into the Servlet's context or the other way around? Because when I use both, it instantiates every bean twice (except for the DefaultAnnotationHandler, and provided that I've set context-param's contextConfigLocation to the servlet config file. If I make a separate config file, I need to copy/paste the beans for authentication, or importing the data & business layer, thus making all of these beans twice. How can I keep having them only once?

Comment: The appcontext created by ContextLoaderListener is the parent context of the servlet's appcontext. That means that the beans in the ContextLoaderListener's appcontext are automatically visible to the beans in the servlet's appcontext (but not the other way around). So any that are shared should be declared in the parent.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware of that. I fixed my config accordingly, and now it all works brilliantly. :-) Thank you very much, and thanks for all the other times you've helped me out here. I definitely need to buy you a couple of beers sometime :-)

Comment: aww shucks, y'all are making me blush

Comment: This is not working, when I set two different context xmls, and set <context:component-scan base-package="org.my.app.base.package.path" /> in config xml that is set for ContextConfigListener, I only get white pages, but when that definition is in both files then it works.

Answer (score 1):

The web.xml of the Spring MVC basic app doesn't have a ContextLoaderListener though? See https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml.

Reason I ask is because I'm getting the following error in my application:

ERROR [[Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

and I don't have a ContextLoaderListener (which is likely to cause the issue).

Any thoughts as to why the MVC basic app will work?

Comment: This mvc-basic works because it uses only the filter org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter and this filter does not need the Spring Application Context to work.