# Use a ContextLoaderListener in accordance with DispatchServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to use both ContextLoaderListener (so that I can pass Spring Beans to my servlet) as well as DispatchServlet (Spring MVC). However, currently I have to pass init param to these both class initializer:

```
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml
</param-value>
```

So, I use the same xml for these both classes. Wonder if it would lead to my beans being initialized twice? If yes, how would I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For both `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`, the `contextConfigLocation` parameter is optional.

`ContextLoaderListener` defaults to `/WEB-INF/application.xml`, `DispatcherServlet` defaults to `/WEB-INF/servletname-servlet.xml`.

If you set these parameters explicitly, you should *not* set them to the same value. The `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` should have contexts with different sets of bean definitions, since otherwise, as you say, the beans will be instantiated twice.

Comment: So, there's no way for these two to share the same set of beans?

Comment: @Phuong: The servlet's beans will have access to the beans in the context loaded by the listener. The contexts form a parent-child relationship. The beans are "owned" by the parent, but visible to the child

Comment: Hmm, I read one of your post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464881/defaultannotationhandlermapping-via-contextloaderlistener-instead-of-dispatcherse, and the problem was explained much cleaner. I will try to see whether I can avoid duplicating my beans. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @skaffman I've tried to apply your suggestiong but i've run into issue using ressource `<mvc:resources mapping="/content/games/**" location="file:${admin.content.path}/Games/Images/" />` with file like this. I've posted a thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311741/how-to-configure-dispatcherservlet-and-contextloaderlistener-in-order-to-give-wa .I would be grateful if you can look into it.Thanks

Answer (score 6):

to force *DispatcherServlet* initialization use *context* from *ContextLoaderListener* you should set *contextConfigLocation* as empty:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also can try this, 
--in bean context exclude controller scan

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.example">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

and in dispatcher servle context, scan only controller

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.example"  use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<context:annotation-config/>
```

https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-component-scan-include-and-exclude-filter-example